# object(stdClass) data retrieving error

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, class

I am using codeigniter php framework and I fetched data using codeigniter database functions and store it in a variable its structure is object(stdClass) when I tried to fetch row data using foreach loop it show error

```
foreach ($cat_data as $row_cat)
{       
    echo $row_cat->id . " " . $row_cat->name;       
}
```

It returns Message:

> Trying to get property of non-object

and when I use `echo $row_cat;` in foreach loop it show me only first row

In my database 3 records exists

Comment: try this `var_dump($cat_data)` and post in your question

Comment: post a code how you fetch data from db. It just might be you are fetching array instead of object.

Comment: Update the question, put the Controller function, and model function too. I can help you, but I need to see more code.

Comment: Put the `controller` & `model` code so i can figure out what is problem...

Answer (score 0):

If you do not get an error when you `echo $row_cat` then you are calling the wrong method to retrieve results.

You should be calling the `query->result()` method instead of the `query->row()` method.

Using the `row` method is returning a single row.  Your `foreach` is looping through the properties of a single record and not an array of results.